# Catching exception when device off?

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await, midi

I'm developing an application to connect sensors to Windows. I am using Windows.Device.Midi to connect to my sensors. And I'm trying to detect when the device is off.

Here's what I tried, according to samples I found:

```py
try
     {
       //Creates a MidiInPort object for the specified device.
       currentMidiInputDevice = await MidiInPort.FromIdAsync(devInfo.Id);

       if (currentMidiInputDevice == null)
       {

          Debug.WriteLine("Failed to connect to device.");
          return;
        }
     }

catch (Exception ex) 
     {
          Debug.WriteLine("Bluetooth radio is not on.");
     }
```

But when I run my program nothing shows up. When I try to connect it just freezes for a couple of seconds but nothing else...

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Can you please mention what do you expect to show up ? Are you expecting a log to show up ? From what I see above, if the connection is successful, nothing would be printed.

Comment: Is this a console app? How is this method called (from `Main`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560271/working-with-midi-in-windows-store-app-win-8-1

Comment: Midi is ancient and based on serial ports, they are not plug+play devices so you can't detect state.  The "Bluetooth radio is not on" diagnostic is very strange, more likely to have something to do with a delay.

Comment: I writing a wpf application. I have an interface where the user can connect to bluetooth sensors that sends MIDI. When a device is paired it appears in a listview. And when the user select it, I try to connect to the device
What I am trying to achieve is showing up a pop up message when the device is off. In other word trying to detect that the connexion wasn't successful

Comment: Add more `Debug.WriteLine`s so that you see which call hangs or succeeds.